# How to send escape sequences over ssh connection in Paramiko for example ESC+E.Can someone send a link to a list

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko

I am trying to send ESC+E and other combinations with ESC key over ssh using Paramiko in Python but unable to find a list which can guide.
Can someone please help

```
import paramiko
import time
import os
import sys
time.sleep(1)

ip = "x"
host = ip
username = "aaa"
password = "ffffffffff"

ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip,username=username,password=password,port=5022)
channel=ssh.invoke_shell()
time.sleep(2)
channel.send("W2KTT\n")
time.sleep(5)
output=channel.recv(9999)
print output
channel.send("display alarms \n")
time.sleep(5)
output=channel.recv(9999)
print output
time.sleep(1)
channel.send("\t \t \t n \x1B3 ") #need to send ESC+E key combination here
```

Comment: No the two keys need to be pressed at the same time to run a command in this ssh window. This is an Avaya Media server connected over SAT.So to submit a command in this window ESC+E key need to be pressed together.

Comment: This will probably be covered in ECMA terminal specifications: [ECMA-35](https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-35/) and [ECMA-48](https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-48/).